# Change input field type to read only using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am making a form. trying to make input field read only on the base of the value entered.

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br/>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female <br/>
Age:<input type="text" name="age" id="age" size="20">
Hobbies:<input type="text" name="hobbies" id="hobbies" size="20"><br/>
Phone:<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="20"><br/>
```

if some click on female then the text fields having id's "age" & "phone" becomes read only and changes the background color to grey.

Kindly guide me how to make the input input to read only.

Comment: `document.getElementById("age").readonly = true`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking to disable the input.

Using jQuery:

```
$(".inputname").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: I would be more willing to look over your attempt and guide you from there. Could you post your attempt at a solution?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpeuetvx/)

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" onchange="checkthatshit('male');" value="male">Male<br/>
<input type="radio" name="sex" onchange="checkthatshit(this);" value="female">Female <br/>
Age:<input type="text" name="age" id="age" size="20">
Hobbies:<input type="text" name="hobbies" id="hobbies" size="20"><br/>
Phone:<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" size="20"><br/>
```

And th JS

```
<script>
function checkthatshit(el){
    if(el !== "male" && el.checked){
        document.getElementById('age').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('hobbies').disabled = true;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('hobbies').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('age').disabled = false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then use the below snippet to add or remove readonly attributes on gender select.

**jQuery Code**

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){        
    if($(this).val() == 'female'){
        $("#age").attr("readonly", "readonly");
        $("#phone").attr("readonly", "readonly");
    }else {
        $("#age").removeAttr("readonly");
        $("#phone").removeAttr("readonly");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/01vqyL9f/